# Why am I getting 500 Internal server error using jquery ajax and python bottle?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, bottle, internal-server-error

I am trying to perform this AJAX post but for some reason I am getting a server 500 error. I can't see any error in the python code. So the problem seems to be on the callback. I am posting the code that I am using presently. Anyone?

Html form part is the front end html part how the form is written

```
<form method="post"  id="uploadform" onsubmit="formupload()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="upload_button">Upload File</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Th AJAX call is made to the python code and alerts 'upload fail':

```
function formupload(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadEmpData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#uploadform').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            alert('file uploaded successfully');
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('upload fail');
            //console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The python bottle part where the function is created and data is being received from AJAX request:

```
def uploadEmpData():
data = request.files.get('file')
data.save('files/',overwrite=True)
if data and data.file:
    return json_dumps("File uploaded successfully")
return json_dumps({'error':'Permission Denied.'})
```

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is in your Python code on the server. Check the network tab for a description of the error arising from the request. Also note that you're calling `preventDefault()` on the global `event` object, presumably you need to change that to a form submission event. You also cannot serialize a file input. You need to send a multipart request using FormData

Answer (score 0):

You are ajaxing without without blocking the submit.

Remove `onsubmit="formupload()"` and change the script to this, assuming that would work in the first place.

Have a read of this too: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#uploadform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/uploadEmpData',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#uploadform').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('file uploaded successfully');
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('upload fail');
        //console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This in itself wouldn't cause a 500 error. There's quite a few issues in fact, such as attempting to serialize a file input.

Comment: It might if the form is submitted, interrupting the ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use  instead of "Submit" and remove event.preventDefault() from your function and then try. And if it still give the error, then check the serialized data you send.

Comment: Sorry but type="button" was not get printed in above answer. So I mean to say use input type='button' instead of "submit" and remove event.preventDefault() from your function.